# Rmarkdown Error: "! Paragraph ended before \@fileswith@ptions was complete"

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I am rendering pdf_document from an rmarkdown document. In this document I make ten latex tables (latex function from Hmisc package) in a for loop.

E.g the rmarkdown code looks like this:

````
---
title: "test"
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: lualatex
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 3
  html_document: default
header-includes:
- \usepackage[dutch]{babel}
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \pagestyle{fancy}
- \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{title}
- \usepackage{dcolumn}
- \usepackage[here]

---
```{r}
library(Hmisc)
```

```{r results="asis",tidy=FALSE,eval=TRUE,echo=FALSE,message=FALSE, error=FALSE, warning=FALSE, comment = NA}
data_object <- structure(list(test = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("test1", 
"test2"), class = "factor"), test2 = structure(1:4, .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("test", "test2"
), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")

   for (i in 1:10){
     latex(data_object, title='',file='',caption="title")

   }
```
````

I get this error:

```
    ! Paragraph ended before \@fileswith@ptions was complete.
<to be read again> 
\par 
l.101 

pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF from TeX source
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
```

How can I make sure paragraph is not ended before finishing the tables?

Comment: `\usepackage[here]` in the `header-includes` is causing the problem. Remove it or replace it by a valid `\usepackage[opt]{pkg}`

Comment: @scoa  thank you for your response. I need that package in order to place the tables exactly where I want in the final document. Do you know a valid package that does the same?

Comment: is "here" the name of the package? Then, `\usepackage{here}`. The problem is that you have `[` to set the options, but no `{`, so your `\usepackage` is not complete

Comment: that's it! I can't believe I didn't see that before. It's so plain simple. I guess it's related to the fact that I am a newby with latex. If you please, I will add this as an answer.

Comment: well, latex error messages aren't clear. I voted to close your question as a typographical error because it is unlikely the answer will benefit to someone else

Comment: I agree. Thanks for the help anyway. Most appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error is common when packages aren't called with brackets {}. Try this substitute in your code:

```
#Change this:
- \usepackage[here]

#To this:
- \usepackage{here}
```