# Rmarkdown: Paragraph ended before \Gin@ii was complete

Tags: pdf, r-markdown, rstudio, knitr

I am getting the following error

```
! Paragraph ended before \Gin@ii was complete.
<to be read again> 
\par 
l.398
```

when trying to knit into pdf the following Rmarkdown in Rstudio, which involves defining a variant of `\includegraphics`.

```
---
output:
  pdf_document: 
    latex_engine: lualatex
header-include:
  - usepackage{graphicx}
---

\newcommand\IG[1]{\includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{#1}}

\IG{test.png}
```

Weirdly, the tex output does compile correctly when I execute it through lulatex *outside* of Rstudio (yes, I do have to use lualatex here).

The error seems to be related to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37650/paragraph-ended-before-giniii-was-complete-while-inserting-image-with-inclu and [Rmarkdown Error: "! Paragraph ended before \@fileswith@ptions was complete"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566771/rmarkdown-error-paragraph-ended-before-fileswithptions-was-complete), but none of the solutions there help and I can't figure out what's going wrong in my case.

**Edit:** It weirdly seems like the error comes and goes. I get it sometimes, but not others (I just re-ran the above code and it went through this time).

Comment: Just edited the question to remove unnecessary elements from the header, specifically "title: "Test"
output:
  pdf_document: 
    latex_engine: lualatex
    keep_tex: yes
  html_document: default
date: "2022-12-06"". Just putting this here in case you wonder why these elements are featured in Julian's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `\newcommand` to the YAML header, i.e.

```
---
title: "Test"
output:
  pdf_document: 
    latex_engine: lualatex
    keep_tex: yes
  html_document: default
date: "2022-12-06"
header-include:
  - usepackage{graphicx}
  - \newcommand\IG[1]{\includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{#1}}
---
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there no way to define the new command in the body of the document? I should have included it in the question (or perhaps ask a new question about it), but I am thinking about using a variable as part of the definition of the new command. Something like `\newcommand\IG[1]{\includegraphics[width = [SOME R VARIABLE]*\textwidth]{#1}}` which is why I defined the command in the document rather than in the YAML header.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another workaround I found.

````
---
output:
  pdf_document: 
    latex_engine: lualatex
    keep_tex: yes
header-include:
  - usepackage{graphicx}
---

```{r}
IG <- function(x){
  return(paste0('\\includegraphics[width = \\textwidth]{', x, '}'))
}
```

`r IG('test.png')`
````

It's not exactly in the spirit of defining a new LaTex command, but for most (all?) practical purposes, it has the same effect.

In building the R function that outputs the "new command", you just have to be careful to escape the backslash characters with a second backslash.

Although it wasn't something I asked about in my original question, one thing I like about this second solution is it easily allows to make parameters of the "new command" a function of R variables. For example:

````
---
output:
  pdf_document: 
    latex_engine: lualatex
    keep_tex: yes
header-include:
  - usepackage{graphicx}
---

```{r}
IG <- function(x,y){
  return(paste0('\\includegraphics[width =', y, '\\textwidth]{', x, '}'))
}
```

`r IG('test.png', '0.8')`
````